# Make Grid Div responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

```css
.subcategory-main-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, max-content);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  column-gap: 4%;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 360px;
  @media @tabletScreens {
    height: 280px;
  }
  @media @mobileScreens {
    height: 450px;
    row-gap: 30px;
    column-gap: 7%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content);
  }
}

.subcategory-image-container {
  width: 278px;
  height: 278px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-container">
  <div class="subcategory-main-wrapper">
    <div class="subcategory-container">
      <div class="subcategory-image-container">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subcategory-container">
      <div class="subcategory-image-container">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subcategory-container">
      <div class="subcategory-image-container">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subcategory-container">
      <div class="subcategory-image-container">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to make the circle Div resize proportionally so that it maintains it aspect ratio. However this not happening. Below are the images

[How it should look like when the screen is resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqQlw.png)

[How it looks like!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXOFr.png)

The width of this grid extends the width of the browser. I want the columns and the contents in them to be resized based on the size of the browser screen. Below is my code.

```
.subcategory-main-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, max-content);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    column-gap: 4%;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 360px;
    @media @tabletScreens{
        height: 280px;
        bottom: 12px;
    }
    @media @mobileScreens {
        height: 450px;
        bottom: 35px;
        row-gap: 30px;
        column-gap: 7%;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content);
    }
}
.subcategory-image-container{
    width: 278px;
    height: 278px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="category-container">
<div class="subcategory-main-wrapper">
        <div class="subcategory-container">
        {% if model.config.titleSubCategoryImageOne %}
        <div id="image-1-{{model.id}}" class="subcategory-image-container">
            
        </div>
            <div class="subcategory-title">
                <a href="{{model.config.subCategoryLinkOne}}">
                    {{model.config.titleSubCategoryImageOne}}
                </a>    
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help resolve this. I have tried using flex display but the columns get squezed also. However grid works best for all screen sizes as the circle does not get squezzed.

Comment: first of all, you also have an unclosed `div` in your HTML snippet. you also have a fixed `width` and `height` on `.subcategory-image-container`. There are many ways to make an element responsive, first step is replacing those fixed sizing values

Comment: What pre processor are you using? And could you make your code into a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi I have added a snippet, pls check if this how it should be, coz this is this my first time doing snippet.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti Im using less files and added the snipper as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my code.
I changed the below line
from

`grid-template-columns: repeat(4, max-content);`

to

`grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20%;`
and

```
.subcategory-image-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```